# MapServer dynamic rotation

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I have a MapServer project where the vector map is rotated on the client window (LeafLet plugin) but I need labels and icons to remain "north-up".

I know the STYLE allows ANGLE but it can be static or loaded from the query.

```
    LAYER
        NAME ...
        STATUS ON
        TYPE POINT
        CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
        CONNECTION "... port=5432"
        DATA "geom from tablename using unique table_id using srid=3857"
        CLASS
            STYLE
                ANGLE [maprotation] //example of table name
                ...
                SIZE 6
            END
        END
    END
```

In this case, *maprotation* is read from the table but that's not what I need.
I can pass an extra parameter in the WMS query like:

```
tablelayer.updateParams({'maprotationvalue': angledegree});
```

This kind of parameters can be easily used in a VALIDATION or FILTER section of the .map file like:

````
FILTER ('[id]' = '%maprotationvalue%')```


What I'd like to have is something like:
````

```
LAYER
    NAME ...
    STATUS ON
    TYPE POINT
    CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
    CONNECTION "... port=5432"
    DATA "geom from tablename using unique table_id using srid=3857"
    CLASS
        STYLE
            ANGLE ['%maprotationvalue%']
            ...
            SIZE 6
        END
    END
END
```

```
...in order to have a true runtime rotation of the map based on the client requests but keeping the right label and icon orientation.

One of the things I tried was to build a query like:
```

SELECT %maprotationvalue% AS maprotation, geom FROM ...

```
That would allow to have a result field with the content I need but I wasn't able to find the right syntax for MapServer.

Have you any idea?
```